# Use font in XeTeX not installed on my system

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

Using XeLaTeX, how can I use a font that I have downloaded in a folder, but have not installed on my system? I have tried to specify the path in `setmainfont{Path = C:/MyFolder/MyFonts/`, but I receive the error message `fontspec error: "font-not-found"`

Based on what I have found googling, I have tried these options, but they all give the same error message:

```
\setmainfont{Path = C:/MyFolder/MyFonts/}{LinLibertine_Rah.ttf}
\setmainfont{Path = C:/MyFolder/MyFonts/LinLibertine_Rah.ttf}
\setmainfont{Path = C:/MyFolder/MyFonts/}{LinLibertine}
\setmainfont{Path = C:/MyFolder/MyFonts/LinLibertine}
\setmainfont{Path = C:/MyFolder/MyFonts/}{Linux Libertine}
\setmainfont{Path = C:/MyFolder/MyFonts/Linux Libertine}
\setmainfont[Path = C:/MyFolder/MyFonts/]{LinLibertine_Rah.ttf}
\setmainfont[Path = C:/MyFolder/MyFonts/LinLibertine_Rah.ttf]
\setmainfont[Path = C:/MyFolder/MyFonts/]{LinLibertine}
\setmainfont[Path = C:/MyFolder/MyFonts/LinLibertine]
\setmainfont[Path = C:/MyFolder/MyFonts/]{Linux Libertine}
\setmainfont[Path = C:/MyFolder/MyFonts/Linux Libertine]
```

Comment: Shouldn't path in Windows be using backslashes as directory delimiters? Should it be `C:\MyFolder\Myfonts\ `?

Comment: I tried (on win xp with miktex 2.9.) `\setmainfont[Path = J:/Install/Schriften/]{Inconsolata.otf}` and the font was found. Are your folders really called "MyFolder" and "MyFonts" or do the real names contain things like space or unusual chars which could lead to problems?

Comment: I've stopped using spaces in names of folders and files, and replaced them with underscores. It turns out that was what XeTeX couldn't read. Once I removed the underscores, it worked.

Comment: @Sverre: Don't edit the answer into the question. Leave the original question and add the answer with the "Your answer" form below. Answering your own questions is explicitly encouraged.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I've done so now (and rolled back the original question).

Comment: @ArTourter: For many years, Windows accepts paths with /.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on the comments and suggestions I received, I'm providing the solution here.

```
\setmainfont[   Path              = C:/MyStuff/Fonts/LinLibertineTTF/,
                Extension         = .ttf,
                BoldFont          = LinLibertine_RBah,
                ItalicFont        = LinLibertine_RIah,
                BoldItalicFont    = LinLibertine_RBIah,
                SmallCapsFeatures = {Letters = SmallCaps},
                Numbers           = OldStyle
            ]{LinLibertine_Rah}
```

Avoid spaces and underscores in your path.

Answer (score 6):

Did you try to change the first set of curly brackets to square brackets? That is:

```
\setmainfont[Path=C:/MyFolder/MyFonts/]{LinLibertine_Rah.ttf}
```

See [Fontspec documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fontspec/fontspec.pdf) v2.2b, pp. 7–8.

Comment: I've tried it now - and added the attempts to my question.

Comment: @Sverre It may be that fontspec does not parse windows-like path specifications. The following example works on my linux box. \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[ExternalLocation=./randomFolder/]{ZnikomitNo24}

\begin{document}
Text.
\end{document}

Comment: @Sverre I agree with Ekin. Presumably if you have a file at `C:/MyFolder/MyFonts/LinLibertine_Rah.ttf` then your (currently) 7th example should have worked. Your other attempts are largely gibberish.